# Передача значений элементов из HTML в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, table

Имеется HTML страничка с формой, при отправке которой пользователю возвращается табличка с данными из БД. В этом случае из select/input PHP может получить данные формы и обработать запрос.

Рядом с каждой записью должна находиться кнопка "Удалить", при нажатии на которую php скрипт будет забирать значение одного из столбцов в данной строчке и отправлять на запрос в БД, и здесь уже возникает сложность

Вид примерно такой:
|id|number|date______|  **УДАЛИТЬ**
|1 |123413|09.09.2021|  **УДАЛИТЬ**
|2 |438932|08.07.2021|  **УДАЛИТЬ**
|3 |549594|07.08.2021|  **УДАЛИТЬ**
|4 |349131|04.06.2021|  **УДАЛИТЬ**

1. Каким образом передать значение number в HTML-документе в PHP?
2. Как кнопка "Удалить" будет ссылаться на значение столбца именно в своей строчке?

Только начал изучать PHP, поэтому многого могу не знать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: передача данных осуществляется с помощью get/post запросов. Для изменения состояния используются post запросы. Для выполнения пост-запроса необходимо реализовать форму `<form method="post">`. параметры формы `<input name="..">` буду уходить на сервер и пополнять массив `$_POST` из которого вы можете брать данные и далее реализовывать логику удаления или чего-то еще. Если вам хочется делать удаление без перезагрузки всей страницы, то следует использовать ajax

Comment: @teran Мне нужно, чтобы при кнопке "Удалить" пхп скрипт забирал данные HTML элемента, в данном случае значение столбца number. После чего отправлял их на запрос в БД. И насколько я понимаю, я должен каким то образом взять это значение с помощью js и передать в php

Comment: повторюсь, оберните вашу кнопку в `form mehod=post` добавье туда нужные поля как `input type="hidden"`.

Comment: @teran Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: @teran Передать значение удалось, сделал инпуты в табличке, но проблема с кнопкой, она входит в форму, но не понимаю, как сделать обработчик

Comment: указать `<form action="pah/to/script.php"` и там посмотреть содержимое `$_POST`

Comment: @teran Получается, но нужно, чтобы туда еще параметр определенный передавался и не открывалась новая страница

Comment: для передачи еще параметров, как написано выше, следует использовать `<input type="hidden"` в форме. Чтобы не открывалась новая страница надо идти двумя путями 1) тот которым вы уже идете. После обработки данных надо сделать редирект на исходную страницу (либо обработку делать в том же файле, что и выводит вашу таблицу (но все равно столкнетесь с проблемой ф5 и придете к редиректу)) 2) второй вариант - использовать аякс. Еще следует обратить внимание на то что ваш вопрос закрыли со ссылкой на учебные материалы и книги по пхп, уверен, вам следует сначала что-нибудь почитать

Comment: @ttraceroute можно использовать ajax запросы (в js это fetch или xmlhttprequest), чтобы отправлять данные без перезагрузки страницы, в js указываете уже путь к action файлу, а в html убираете `<form action="">`